# Subtracking into from Dates

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have some data that will looks like this:

```
       Dates  Delta
0 2022-10-01     10
1 2022-10-01     21
2 2022-10-01     34
```

I am trying to add a new column, where I can subtract the number in the `Delta` column from the date in the `Dates` column.  Ideally, the output will look like this (i did this by hand so if the dates are wrong, please excuse me).

```
        Dates  Delta CalculatedDate
0  2022-10-01     10     2022-09-21
1  2022-10-01     21     2022-09-10
2  2022-10-01     34     2022-08-23
```

I've tried various versions of this and I'm not having any luck.

```
# importing libraries to create and manipulate toy data
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

# create toy data
df = pd.DataFrame({'Dates': ['2022-10-01', '2022-10-01', '2022-10-01'],
                  'Delta': [10, 21, 34]})

# cast the `Dates` column as dates
df['Dates'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Dates'])



##### Need help here
# Create a new column, showing the calculated date
df['CalculatedDate'] = df['Dates']  - timedelta(days=df['Delta'])
```

Answer (score 1):

```
df['CalculatedDate'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Dates']) - pd.TimedeltaIndex(df['Delta'], unit='D')
```

`df`

```
    Dates       Delta   CalculatedDate
0   2022-10-01  10      2022-09-21
1   2022-10-01  21      2022-09-10
2   2022-10-01  34      2022-08-28
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way to do it

```
# for each row subtract the delta from the date in the row
# using Day offset

df['calculatedDate']= df.apply(lambda x: x['Dates'] - pd.offsets.Day(x['Delta']), axis=1)
df
```

```
Dates   Delta   calculatedDate
0   2022-10-01  10  2022-09-21
1   2022-10-01  21  2022-09-10
2   2022-10-01  34  2022-08-28
```

Answer (score 0):

I see Naveed and Panda has a fix that works great, suggesting the one I came up with as well:

```
for x in range(len(df)):
    df.loc[x,'CalculatedDate'] = df.loc[x, 'Dates']  - timedelta(days=int(df.loc[x, 'Delta']))
print(df)
```

Put it in a for loop so that you can index through each row and do each row individually. Also make df['CalculatedDate'] into df.loc[x,'CalculatedDate']. This way you will do each row individually. Hope this helps